# Make sync request with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, nsurlsession

I call some function in another thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
     self.someFunction()
}
```

Then in this function i want do synchronous request:

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
let dataSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
guard let responseData = data else {
    print("Error: did not receive data")
    return
}
guard error == nil else {
    print("error calling GET")
    print(error)
    return
    }
    print("ASYNC")
})
task.resume()

dispatch_semaphore_wait(dataSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

print("SYNC")
```

But thread stops `dispatch_semaphore_wait(dataSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)` at this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never signaled the semaphore, put this at the end of your completion handler:

```
dispatch_semaphore_signal(dataSemaphore)
```

Comment: thanks, and can you help, how to set timeoutInterval to this function ? If we don't have response in 30 seconds for example, continiue

Comment: @Arti Just replace `DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER` with `dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(numberOfSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))`

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answer here is technically correct, I feel the need to post a second answer, asking *why* you're doing this....

Synchronous networking is *almost never* the right way to do anything.  Instead, you really should make the rest of the function be a block that gets run when the request finishes.

The fact that it is technically possible to create a synchronous wrapper for an async API doesn't negate the fact that doing so blocks whatever thread is running this code, so unless you're in a situation where you need to enforce some sort of strict ordering over network requests, synchronous requests are generally a bad idea, and even then, they aren't a *good* idea.

Comment: I should make N requests. They call each other after finish. So i did this like: I call one function asynchronous, and all other requests in this function make synchronous.